# QLPreviewController as subview

Tags: pdf, uiview, datasource, subview, qlpreviewcontroller

I have a little problem with the use of QLPreviewController. Indeed, I have to display a PDF in my application and this class works fine if I push the controller in the UINavigationController application. For this, I use this tutorial : (http://iosdevelopertips.com/data-file-management/preview-documents-with-qlpreviewcontroller.html).

The problem is that I need a UIToolbar at bottom of the view to accompany the PDF. So I created a new controller with a UIToolBar and a QLPreviewController but the QLPreviewController doesn't appear: my view for the QLPreviewController's view stay white.

This is the initialization code and adding the controller to the view:

```
PdfReaderViewController = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
[PdfReaderViewController setDataSource:self];
[PdfReaderViewController setDelegate:self];
[PdfReaderViewController.view setFrame:myViewForPdfReader.frame];
[PdfReaderViewController setCurrentPreviewItemIndex:sollIndex];
vuePourLecteurPDF = PdfReaderViewController.view;    
[PdfReaderViewController reloadData];
```

I notice that one of two methods... :

```
- (id <QLPreviewItem>) previewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller previewItemAtIndex: (NSInteger) index;
```

of the QLPreviewControllerDataSource is not called when reloadData. The second returns a positive integer:

```
- (NSInteger) numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller;
```

I don't understand the problem, I know only that both methods are correct because i tested by pushing the QLPreviewController in the UINavigationController.

I read some posts:

[Customizing QLPreviewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386492/customizing-qlpreviewcontroller)

[Adding QLPreviewController as subview doesn't load PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043305/adding-qlpreviewcontroller-as-subview-doesnt-load-pdf)

[QLPreviewController's view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091027/qlpreviewcontrollers-view)

[blank QLPreviewController in iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009637/blank-qlpreviewcontroller-in-ios-application)

... but this does not help me

Answer (score 2):

embedd the QLPreviewController as a childViewController in new custom container view controller.
dont try to mess with its view structure directly IMO